# Regarding combinatorics on dice...

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

The problem:

> If you are to roll a die five times, what is the probability the fifth die is not a repetition?

Apparently the answer is $$\frac{6\cdot5^4}{6^5}$$ 
but I don't really see why. What that answer says to me is that "We have 6 options for the first roll and then for each roll after that we have 5 options for each." That means, to me, that there can indeed be repetition on the 5th roll, which is not what we're going for! My original thought for this was to just opt out of repetition completely, but that leaves only one of the cases. Can anyone help me understand the logic behind this problem?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the description of the experiment. What does it mean that the fifth die is not a repetition? Does it mean that the first five rolls gave the same number and the fifth was different? Or does it mean that the first three were arbitrary but the last two were different? In the latter case the result is obviously $\frac{5}{6}$.

Comment: I was thinking $\frac{5}{6}$ at one point, too. Alas, TorisonSquid's description is what it is. In other words, the former.

The way I look at it now, is that we have six cases. Each case is 5 choices for the first 4 rolls, and then which ever number we've let out, the fifth roll with be left out option of the first 4 rolls. Each case has the same probability of $\frac{(5^4)\cdot 1}{6^5}$ so summing up the six cases gives us our answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $6^5$ possible sequences of die rolls, which explains the denominator. Now, given a number from 1 to 6, there are $5^4$ ways we can roll the die 5 times and get this number last and ONLY last (each of the first 4 rolls has 6-1=5 possibilities).  So the number of rolls where the last is not a repeat is $6\cdot5^4$, explaining the numerator.

Comment: Ah thank you sir. This makes plenty of sense now.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question can be interpreted as: If you roll a die 5 times, what is the probability that the first roll is different from the other 4 rolls? Now, imagine rolling the first die. You will get a value from 1 to 6, call it $a$. Then, the probability that the second roll isn't $a$ is $\frac56$. Assuming each roll is independent, the probability that the third roll isn't $a$ is also $\frac56$. Continuing this way we see that the probability we wish to calculate is equal to $(\frac56)^4$. Can anyone correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: I think that is certainly a good way to look at it, since that way of thinking leads us $\frac{6\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5}{6^5}$ off the bat. :)

Comment: Nice reformulation of the problem.